# Retain Specific values in Excel sheet and remove others and get count of how many times repeated vbscript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to remove all in excel data except for rows 'containing' the name "abc".I am trying to update the excel sheet and then get the count of how many times each duplicate has repeated.The output should be another excel sheet in which i have the condensed duplicate values along with the count i got previously.

What I have done: To get the count of duplicate value I used this:

```
      =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8, A1
```

But how can i remove the other values and put the remaining in a new Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "RowNo" column with the row number or any other Row Id. Next use **Microsoft Query** in the output Excel file e.g.:

```
SELECT S1.Val, COUNT(S1.Val) FROM `C:\Book1.xls`.`Sheet1$` as S1 
INNER JOIN `C:\Book1.xls`.`Sheet1$` as S2 
WHERE S1.Val = S2.Val and S1.RowNo > S2.RowNo
GROUP BY S1.Val
```

Additionally to remove data not containing e.g. 'abc' you can add another condition to the WHERE clause: S1.Val NOT LIKE "*abc*". See below:

```
 SELECT S1.Val, COUNT(S1.Val) FROM `C:\Book1.xls`.`Sheet1$` as S1 
    INNER JOIN `C:\Book1.xls`.`Sheet1$` as S2 
    WHERE S1.Val = S2.Val and S1.RowNo > S2.RowNo AND S1.Val NOT LIKE "*abc*"
    GROUP BY S1.Val
```

Feel free to test different SQL with my AddIn: [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/).

To set this up via VBscript:

1. Step 1: Create an Excel with this Microsoft Query
2. Step 2: Create a VBscript that will refresh the Microsoft Query in the Excel file (See an example here of how to connect to an Excel file from VBscript [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-schedule-excel-macros-to-run-periodically/)).

Comment: Sure. Just create the Workbook with this query and refresh it via VBscript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Really exited to try

Comment: No problem! Please mark as answer to close this question

Comment: I would also want to delete existing data which is not containing 'abc'.How could i do tha.